# How to hide or cloak download links inside wordpress and don't allow access if they are directly copy pasted?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, url, cloaking

I provide some download links via external direct download urls which are htaccess redirected by `https://example.com/resources/downloadlink.html` urls. I'd like to hide or cloak these links because the wp members can still access to the links and download them if they don't logged in and simply copy and paste them into their browsers. So the download button links must show different -cloaked- links to everyone. But actually they have to go for download link. And if they copy past cloaked link into their browser bar it should not go to specified download url.

Firstly i've tried to show every external links from

```
example.com/resources/downloadlink...
```

With this htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /resources https://external.com/directdownload-
```

There are some cloaking plugins to cloak urls but none of them support what i want. 
I want to hide these links or cloak/show different url for all them and that fake urls which are shown to members shouldn't go to download links if they are scraped and copy/pasted into browser bar.

For example: If we show links like `example.com/cloakedurls` then they shouldn't simply access download links if they copy paste these urls.

How to do?

Comment: you cant hide download links that would be a massive security flaw. You need to implement authentication on the machine serving the downloads.

Comment: Ok no way with css or javascript?

Comment: If someone really wants to know the real URL, they can easily get it from the browser.

Comment: but at least we should make it harder to find

Comment: Are you willing to use a custom PHP page? Also, you got to think about storage. These links, are these to files uploaded to Wordpress? Otherwise, are there just a few download links?